# Angular 6 - RouterLinkActive not Working After Page Refresh

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

**Context**

I have a menu with some items. The item which is selected in the router has the class `selected` on it, to change its color.

[image: Menu]

> **Issue**
>
> Everything is working fine when switching the routes, but the when refreshing the page nothing is selected.

---

**Code**

My HTML template looks like this:

```
<div [routerLink]="'link1'" routerLinkActive #link1="routerLinkActive">
    <div [class.selected]="link1.isActive">Link1</div>
</div>
<div [routerLink]="'link2'" routerLinkActive #link2="routerLinkActive">
    <div [class.selected]="link2.isActive">Link2</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you refresh the page on certain route(/site1) or without any route(just /)?

Comment: you're over complicating stuff. `<div routerLink="link1" routerLinkActive="active"> ... `

Comment: @Buczkowski it actually works on two pages

Comment: @Stavm But how would I then conditionaly add a class ?

Comment: `routerLinkActive="active"` is your added class.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a
routerLink="/admin/:adminId/bar"
routerLinkActive="on"
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false, __change_detection_hack__: adminId }"> Link </a>
```

Here, the **change_detection_hack** key will change when the id changes (ie, after navigation has completed and the template is reconciled), which will cause the inputs to change, which will cause the this.update() method to run. And, at that point, the QueryList should be in the proper state.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to bind the selected class name to `routerLinkActive`. 
and the link is missing a '/' 
something like this should work:

```css
a.selected {
  color: red;
}


/* or */

a.selected>span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a routerLink="link1" routerLinkActive="selected">
  <span>link 1</span>
</a>
```

Also, you can play with the CSS selectors if you need to.

hoped I helped  :)